# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z(z+3)(z-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series for

$$\frac{1}{z(z+3)(z-1)^2}$$ in $1 < |z-1| < 4$

So I did the partial fraction decomposition which yields:

$$\frac{1}{4(-1+z)^2} - \frac{5}{16(-1+z)} + \frac{1}{3z} - \frac{1}{48(3+z)}$$

Can anyone help me finish this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Partial fraction expansion reveals

$$\frac{1}{z(z+3)(z-1)^2}=\frac{1/3}{z}-\frac{1/48}{z+3}-\frac{5/16}{z-1}+\frac{1/4}{(z-1)^2}\tag1$$

The last two terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ constitute part of the Laurent expansion in the annulus $1<|z-1|<4$.

We now expand the first term, $\frac{1/3}{z}$, for $|z-1|>1$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1/3}{z}&=\frac{1/3}{z-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z-1}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (z-1)^{-(n+1)}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we expand the term $\frac{1/48}{z+3}$ for $|z-1|<4$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1/48}{z+3}&=\frac{1/48}{4+(z-1)}\\\\
&=\frac1{192}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-1}{4}\right)^n\tag3
\end{align}$$

Now, assemble the expansion using $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$.

Comment: I can do themn all except the $\frac{1/4}{(z-1)^2}$ what would be the geometric form of that?

Comment: That term is already part of the Laurent expansion in powers of $\frac1{z-1}$.

Comment: I got $-1/4 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (4/(z-1))^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.